# Does wso2 Message broker support fanout exchange?

Tags: c#, wso2, rabbitmq

I am fairly new to wso2 message broker and working on a poc.
We are trying to use WSO2 Message broker with RabbitMQ C#.
I get an error in the Consumer code, when I bind the queue to the fanout exchange.
Here is the code that errors out:

```
_channel.ExchangeDeclare("amq.fanout", "fanout");
string queueName = _channel.QueueDeclare();
_channel.QueueBind(queueName, "amq.fanout", "");
```

The exception happens in the third line (QueueBind) of this snippet.

Here is the error
The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=504, text="org.wso2.andes.AMQSecurityException: Permission denied: binding  [error code 403: access refused]", classId=50, methodId=20, cause=

We are using AMQP 0_9_1.

I see that wso2 mb does not provide the fanout exchange by default. I added the following snippet to the qpid.virtualhosts.xml file

```
   <exchange>
     <type>fanout</type>
     <name>amq.fanout</name>
   </exchange>
```

When the broker is started, I dont see any errors.

I am not sure if I am missing anything in the setup or code, or does wso2 Message broker support fanout exchange at all?
I could not find any examples for this case either.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have looked into this issue, I can tell WSO2 Message Broker supports only Direct and Topic exchange types. FanOut and Headers exchange types are not supported and it fails when I use them. WSO2 Message Broker is powered by [Andes broker engine](http://docs.wso2.org/display/MB210/Component-Based+Architecture). Andes document talks only about the two messaging patterns based on Queues & Topics and doesn't talk about any exchange types being used. Further digging into the source code by decompiling the WSO2 Message Broker JAR files, I see "amq.direct", "amq.topic", "amq.fanout" and "amq.match" (headers) exchange names being used, but not sure if all were implemented.